# Distinct coset representative and stabilizing an element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G < S_n$ be a permutation group of degree $n$, and let $G^{(i)},0 < i\leq  n$, be the pointwise stabilizer of $\{1,2.., i\}$ in $G$. We set $G^{(0)}= G$. For $0 < i\leq  n$, let $U_i$ be a complete right transveral  for $G^{(i)}$  in $G^{(i-1)}$. If $\psi$ and  $\psi'$  are distinct coset representatives in $U_i$, then

$i^{\psi} \neq i^{\psi'}$

But $\psi,  \psi'$ both fix $\{1,..i-1\}$. If $i^{\psi} = i^{\psi'}$, still $\psi$ and  $\psi'$  can be in distinct coset representatives in $U_i$.

Would anyone eplain why  being $\psi$ and  $\psi'$  in  distinct coset representatives in $U_i$ infers   $i^{\psi} \neq i^{\psi'}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $i^{\psi} = i^{\psi'}$, with $\psi, \psi' \in G^{(i-1)}$.

Then $i^{\psi' \psi^{-1}} = i$, so $\psi' \psi^{-1}  \in G^{(i-1)}$ fixes also $i$, and thus $\psi' \psi^{-1}  \in G^{(i)}$.

It follows that $G^{(i)} \psi = G^{(i)} \psi'$.